# Divergence and conditional convergence, Mertens theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Give $\sum a_n$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ converges conditionally, if the Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ must be divergent?

Comment: Is $a_n$ and $b_n$ positive ?

Comment: @ Chinnapparaj R , not necessary. If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive, then $\sum c_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\geq \sum_na_nb_0$, so it diverges.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR: Since $\sum b_n$ converges conditionally, we can't have $b_n\geq0$ for all $n$, otherwise it would converge absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for a divergent series $\sum a_n$  and a conditionally convergent series $\sum b_n$ to have a  Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ that is not only not divergent, but actually absolutely convergent.  A rather complicated example is constructed in this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1901-002-01/S0002-9947-1901-1500553-8/S0002-9947-1901-1500553-8.pdf).

Surprisingly, it is somewhat less difficult to find two divergent series whose Cauchy product is convergent, as I show [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303251/148510).