# An example: a convergence series, a divergent series, whose Cauchy product is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-product

How to find an example: a convergence series $\sum a_n$, a divergent series $\sum b_n$, whose Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ with $c_n=\sum_{i+j=n}a_ib_j$ is convergent? Is there a simple example?

Comment: What about $a_n = 0, b_n = 1/n$?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Is there any more not such trivial example?

Comment: I know a non trivial example where you have two divergent series and their Cauchy product is convergent. If interested let me know and I will post it

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D.: Such examples are already given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2293968/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314213/42969.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $a_n$ such that $a_{2k}=a_{2k+1}$ for every $k=0,1,2...$. Let be $b_k=(-1)^k$. Then it is
$$
c_{2n}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n} {a_k } b_{2n - k}  = a_0  - a_1  +  \cdots  - a_{2n - 1}  + a_{2n} 
$$
and
$$
c_{2n + 1}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} {a_k } b_{2n - k}  =  - a_0  + a_1  +  \cdots  - a_{2n}  + a_{2n + 1} 
$$
It follows that
$$
s_{2n}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n} {c_k  = a_0 }  + a_2  +  \cdots a_{2n} 
$$
and
$$
s_{2n + 1}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} {c_k  = a_1 }  + a_3  +  \cdots a_{2n + 1} 
$$
If the series 
$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{ + \infty } {a_k } 
$
is convergent we get the required example. For instance we can choose $a_0=a_1=1$, $a_2=a_3=1/2$, $a_4=a_5=1/2^2$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- Take a limit of the form $0\cdot\infty$ and develop the corresponding Taylor series.