# Can the Cauchy product of a conditionally convergent series with itself be absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence, cauchy-product

If $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n$ are two series, their Cauchy product is defined as $\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n$, where $c_n = \sum^n_{k=0} a_k b_{n-k}$.

As [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838373/series-whose-cauchy-product-is-absolutely-convergent-a-general-example) points out, finding two conditionally convergent series whose Cauchy product is absolutely convergent is quite hard, but examples do indeed exist. I also learned that the Cauchy product of a divergent series with itself can be absolutely convergent (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314213/can-the-cauchy-product-of-divergent-series-with-itself-be-convergent)). So do there exists a conditionally convergent series $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n$ such that the Cauchy product of $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n$ with itself is absolutely convergent?

Comment: Interesting question! I thought I might be able to use the binomial series, but the binomial series can't serve as an example due to conflicting requirements ($2\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and $-1 < \text{Re}(\alpha) \le 0$).

Comment: If $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, then $f(z)$ must have radius of convergence equal to exactly $1$. This implies that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1$ and that the series for $f(z)^2$ has radius of convergence at least equal to $1$ (which is necessary for absolute convergence of $\sum_{n \ge 0} c_n$).

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yes, and I was wondering if more can be said about the properties of $f(z)$ :)

Comment: Looking at the taylor series of $\sqrt{x+1}$ at $0$, I would expect divergence for $x=-1$ and convegence for $x=1$, so at $x=1$ its conditionally convergent. But $\sqrt{x+1}^2=x+1$ should have globally convergent taylor series, so enough stuff will cancel out to get absolute convergence if you square the taylor series of $\sqrt{x+1}$. Atleast thats my expectation, maybe the details don't work out.

Comment: Annoyingly $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \binom{1/2}{n} = -1 + 1/2 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 5/128 + \cdots $ converges to $0$. (Proof: the upper bound on $\binom{2n}{n}$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient implies $|\binom{1/2}{n}| = \frac{1}{2n} |\binom{-1/2}{n-1}| = \frac{1}{2n4^{n-1}} \binom{2(n-1)}{n-1} \le \frac{1}{2n 4^{n-1}} \times \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} = \frac{2}{n\sqrt{n}}$, and now use the comparison test to get convergence, then use Abel's Lemma.) So this is an example of the Cauchy square of an absolutely convergent series being absolutely convergent.

Comment: @s.harp Sorry but the taylor series of $\sqrt{x+1}$ converge absolutely at $x=-1$. In fact, I would not be astonished if the example I'm looking for does not exist at all.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a function that is integrable but not absolutely integrable, but is absolutely integrable after convolution with itself? Maybe there's a result about that that carries over to the cauchy product.